# Ionic Angular component renders multiple or infinite times

Tags: angular, components, render, infinite, ionic5

I have a component that for some reason will render multiple times (only goes through constructor and onInit once) and if I have "actions" then it renders infinitely. No, it's not stuck in the loop, the loop renders its one item, and then it tries to re-render the whole component.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { HeaderAction } from '../../models/header-action';
import { UtilsService } from '../../services/utils';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss'],
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()
  public title : string;

  @Input()
  public info : string;

  @Input()
  public actions : HeaderAction[];

  constructor(public utils: UtilsService, private router : Router) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  infinite(){
    console.log("infinite :(")
  }

  showEvent(action : HeaderAction) : boolean {
    console.log("inifinite in loop :(")
    return action.event;
  }

  showRedirect(action : HeaderAction) : boolean {
    return !action.event && !!action.redirect;
  }

}
```

```html
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>{{title}}</ion-title>{{this.infinite()}}
    <ion-icon *ngIf="info" name="information-circle" (click)="utils.onInformationPopup(title,info)"></ion-icon>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let action of this.actions">
      <ion-icon *ngIf="this.showEvent(action)" name="{{action.name}}" (click)="action.event(action.context)"></ion-icon>
      <ion-icon *ngIf="this.showRedirect(action)" [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[action.redirect]" name="{{action.name}}" ></ion-icon>
    </ng-container>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Extra info, this component is a component I use in multiple places so I added it in the declarations and exports of shared.module.ts which is a module that I import in all my pages. I don't think this is at fault though, but maybe it's good to check.

This is without any actions:

[image: Screenshot 1]

This is with actions:

[image: Screenshot 2]

If I comment out the router line then it only renders multiple times even if it has actions to iterate.

Also, the iteration is of the same component id because I added a count and it was incrementing.

Please someone tell me I'm just not seeing something simple!

Comment: could you try to make your component `OnPush`? if it fixes the problem then the reason is somewhere not in this component. Btw with current cimponent logic it is recommended to mark it as OnPush because of performance reasons

Comment: I need to search what OnPush is. Also I just found out that every component renders multiple times. This is very weird

Comment: it is not weird. you probably have several events that cause change detection on your application, and because of your components aren't OnPush the whole components tree tries to find changes in them. Angular "rendering" as you've said is not react rendering. It is fast in most cases even if you are using it wrong. it is just a small piece of code for every component where ONLY binding values are checked by code generated during angular compilation. If you want to improve performance you have to at least study change detection topic in Angular

Comment: I understand your point. Unfortunately there aren't many options for me to learn, just default and on push. I'll trial&error and hopefully will get the results I want. I added onPush on app.component.ts and actually it fixed that problem but broke my routing. Now I need to click twice on each page for it to load. (Loads previous click when clicking something, doens't have to be twice the same thing)

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to Andrei (i don't know if I can tag you sorry) I found a solution.

As he mentioned it has to do with ChangeDetectionStrategy. For smaller projects I guess it's fast enough that you can ignore it.

My first thought was setting the app.component.ts as onPush so that everything is affected. That solved my one problem but broke my routing. Then I figured I need to add it to each page on their onInit so that they know that they have been visited.

However my project is still at a size that can handle some redundancy so I am allowed to only add the onPush in the pages that were having the problem in the first place. (In my instance, the pages that had actions to pass to the header component).

I hope this helps someone else in the future. Thank you Andrei.

If anyone else has a better solution for me, feel free to give me your input.
Merry Christmas